# Cómo poner imagen de fondo en un div de un formulario login responsive?

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap, css3, login

tengo  problemas para poner una imagen de fondo en un div de un formulario login hecho con bootstrap, pero no he logrado hacerlo. La pagina de login tiene en la parte izquierda el formulario de login y en la parte derecha una imagen. 
Aqui les dejo el codigo de lo que llevo hecho:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">

       <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>SOLVentas | Sales Systems</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/form-elements.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/style.css">


    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script 
        src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script 
         src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Favicon and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="ico/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">

    <style type="text/css">

     div.container {
margin: 0 !important;
margin-right: 0 !important;
 padding-right: 0 !important;
padding-left: 0 !important;
  }

  #formulario, #imagen {
/*border: 2px solid red !important;*/
margin-right: 0 !important;
  }

   form input {
   padding: 10px !important;
   border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0,2) !important;
   height: 40px !important;

    }

    button {
    background-color: blue !important;
      }
    /*#imagen {

   background-image: url() !important;

          background-position: center center !important;

    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;

     background-attachment: fixed !important;

     background-size: cover !important;

    background-color: #66999 !important;

          } */
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>



           <!-- Top content -->

       <div class="container" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <div class="row" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="margin: 0; padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0; ">
            <div class="form-top">
                            <div class="form-top-left">
                                <h3>Get Access to your Account</h3>
                                <p>Insert your username and password to Log in:</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-top-right">
                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-bottom" style="background-color: #F3F3F3;">
                            <form role="form" id="frmIngresar" name="frmIngresar" method="post" class="login-form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">User</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="form-username" placeholder="User..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="form-password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-password">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn">Log In</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8" style="background-image: url('img/backgrounds/1.jpg');  width: 66%; min-height: 100vh; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; margin: 0; padding: 0; "></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {   
            $("form#frmIngresar").submit(IngresarSistema);


        function IngresarSistema(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var user = $("#form-username").val();
            var pass = $("#form-password").val();

            $.getJSON("ajax/UsuarioAjax.php?op=IngresarSistema", {user: user, pass: pass}, function(r) {
                if (r) {
                    $(location).attr("href", "acceder.php");
                    //window.location.href = "acceder.php";
                } else {
                    bootbox.alert("Error! Username or password are not correct!");
                    $("#form-username").val("");
                    $("#form-password").val("");
                    $("#form-username").focus();
                }
            });  
        }

        });
    </script>

</body>
```

El resultado es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La parte roja es el espacio que queda entre la imagen y la ventana del navegador. La idea es que ese espacio este ocupado por la imagen. Deberia abarcar todo el contenedor derecho pero eso no sucede. Le he puesto todos los margenes en 0 pero parece no funcionar.

La pagina de login deberia quedar asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo podria conseguir que la imagen abarque todo el div? Cuando el login se visualice en un dispositivo mobil con resolucion menor a 770px de ancho y 400px de alto me gustaria que la imagen ya no apareciera, solo el formulario. Pero no se cómo hacerlo. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: parte de la solución la tienes comentada `background-size: cover !important;`  https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: para la segunda pregunta fijate de definir el estilo para esa columna en este hilo hay varias opciones https://stackoverflow.com/a/45844579/1423096

Comment: el background-size: cover si esta, solo que lo coloque directamente en el atributo style del div. Es decir, esta aqui: <div style="background-size: cover" Revisare los enlaces que me dejaste.

Answer (score 1):

Has probado quitando el **width: 66%** del contenedor de la imagen?, ya con los col de bootstrap le das un width determinado.

Para desaparecer la imagen puedes usar una media quiery en css:

```
 @media (max-width: 770px){
     .nombredeclase{
         display: none;
     }
 }
```

Y le agregas esa clase al div que quieres desaparecer cuando el ancho de la pantalla sea 770px.

Comment: ya que usa bootstrap podría usarlo para ocultar en un breakpoint v3: `hidden-xs-down (hidden-xs)`, v4: `d-none d-sm-block`

Comment: Si, en la documentación sale toda la información, sin embargo para 770px creo que no ejecuta los display none, tendría que compilar con sass el scss de los breakpoints desde _variables.scss, cambiando los valores correspondientes, además si solo quiere desaparecer eso a esa resolución y del resto necesita el comportamiento de bootstrap por defecto, debe hacer un main.css personalizado.

Comment: esa es buena info para ampliar la respuesta ;)

Comment: Si yo probé quitarle el 66% al principio pero la imagen quedaba debajo del formulario, y asi no me convenía.

Comment: Probare el media query y les aviso.

Comment: Ojo, veo que colocas padding en un form y un input en tus estilos de cabecera, te recomiendo colocar un box-sizing: border-box; para que el padding sea hacia dentro y no agrande el div, prueba a ver y nos comentas

Comment: he aplicado el box-sizing y me ha servido. Me he manejado bien con los media query, aunque al final intente que la imagen se estirara y abarcara también todo el alto de la pantalla pero no me ha resultado. De igual forma gracias por la sugerencia y sus aportes.

Comment: Me alegra que te funcionara, para que una imagen o contenedor te abarque la totalidad de la altura del viewport puedes intentar hacer un height: 100vh; y un width: 100%; experimenta a ver que pasa.